# Tikz in the question

Tags: support, feature-request

I wish to add a tikz diagram to one of my questions, but the website doesn't seem to compile. Some help please?

Comment: I don't believe that MathJax supports Tikz. Support for diagrams [has been suggested on the mother meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70933/add-graphviz-support-to-markdown) more than once, but so far the team has so far declined asking for more detail of what you think it would add over preparing [diagrams in external tools](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401/what-software-programs-are-used-to-draw-physics-diagrams-and-what-are-their-rel) and adding them as images.

Comment: @dmckee: Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

Mathjax doesn't support TikZ, and it would be a very heavy script even if it did. Remember that mathjax is compiled on the client side so putting heavy code in it will just end up in making your answer take a lot of time to load.

Instead, make the diagram in LaTeX (`\documentclass[standalone]` is good for this), and upload the image.